# Java - synchronous callback

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the following code which is executed asynchronously. I would like to make it synchronous in order to follow some logical flow but I cannot work out how.

You will see that `scanning` is set to `true` to indicate that the method is still working, at the beginning - I then initiate a `findPrinters(...)` command - this contains a DiscoveryHandler which runs asynchronously - `foundPrinter()` is called each time an item is discovered. `discoveryFinished()` is when the discovery process is successfully completed, and `discoveryError(...)` is called whenever an error occurs.

I rely on something being set in my DiscoveryHandler before I would like to return from this method. Hence why I have `while (scanning)` underneath it. But this feels like a hack to me, and not the correct way of doing things. I cannot get `wait()` and `notify()` working. Can someone tell me what the correct way to do this is please?

```
private boolean findPrinter(final Context ctx) {
    try {
        scanning = true;
        BluetoothDiscoverer.findPrinters(ctx, new DiscoveryHandler() {

            public void foundPrinter(DiscoveredPrinter device) {
                if (device instanceof DiscoveredPrinterBluetooth) {
                    DiscoveredPrinterBluetooth btDevice = (DiscoveredPrinterBluetooth) device;

                    if (btDevice.friendlyName.startsWith("XXXX")) {
                        try {
                            connection = new BluetoothConnection(btDevice.address);
                            connection.open();

                            if (connection.isConnected()) {
                                address = btDevice.address;
                            }
                        } catch (Exception ex) {

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            public void discoveryFinished() {
                scanning = false;
            }

            public void discoveryError(String arg0) {
                scanning = false;
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }

    while (scanning) {}

    return false;
}
```

Comment: I will be returning another value other than `false` once I have the correct implementation running. But that is just a stub for now.

Comment: wait() and notify() works only when you don't want to have a concurrent access to one data using the synchronized keyword

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do this with `CountDownLatch`, which might be the lightest synchronization primitive in `java.util.concurrent`:

```
private boolean findPrinter(final Context ctx) {
    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    final boolean[] result = {false};

    ...

    BluetoothDiscoverer.findPrinters(ctx, new DiscoveryHandler() {

        ...

        public void discoveryFinished() {
            result[0] = true;
            latch.countDown();
        }
    
        public void discoveryError(String arg0) {
            result[0] = false;
            latch.countDown();
        }

        ...
    }

    // before final return
    // wait for 10 seconds for the response
    latch.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    //return the result, it will return false when there is timeout
    return result[0];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a bunch of ways you can do this and `wait()/notify()` is probably not the best since you probably want to return something from your async method. As such I suggest using something like a `BlockingQueue`. Here is a simplified example of how you can do this:

```
private boolean findPrinter(final Context ctx) {
    final BlockingQueue<?> asyncResult = new SynchronousQueue<?>();
    try {
        BluetoothDiscoverer.findPrinters(ctx, new DiscoveryHandler() {

            public void foundPrinter(DiscoveredPrinter device) {
                if (device instanceof DiscoveredPrinterBluetooth) {
                    DiscoveredPrinterBluetooth btDevice = (DiscoveredPrinterBluetooth) device;

                    if (btDevice.friendlyName.startsWith("XXXX")) {
                        try {
                            connection = new BluetoothConnection(btDevice.address);
                            connection.open();

                            if (connection.isConnected()) {
                                address = btDevice.address;
                            }
                        } catch (Exception ex) {

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            public void discoveryFinished() {
                asyncResult.put(true);
            }

            public void discoveryError(String arg0) {
                asyncResult.put(arg0);
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }

    Object result = asyncResult.take();

    if (result instanceof Boolean) {
        return (Boolean) result;
    } else if (result instanceof String) {
        logError((String) result);
    }

    return false;
}
```

One problem with using `SynchronousQueue` here though is that if `discoveryFinished()/discoveryError()` is called more than once, then the thread executing the code asynchronously will block forever since the `SynchronousQueue` assumes there will be exactly one `take()` per every `put()` and will block if a `put()` is made without a corresponding `take()` or vice versa. So if in your case those methods can be called more than once you would probably use a different kind of `BlockingQueue` instead (see [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html)).

Comment: Thanks! Slight syntax error - you'll need to declare asyncResult outside the try/catch block - otherwise I'm going to give this a go - thanks!

Comment: Yeah sorry I just typed this up in the answer. Fixed now.